Linear regression with interactions in R: plot fitted data with original
I was doing linear regression with interactions in R 4.4.1. Here's my model:
library("tidyverse")
library("broom")

model <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Solar.R:Temp, data = airquality)
summary(model)

Output:
Call:
lm(formula = Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Solar.R:Temp, data = airquality)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-39.538 -12.689  -1.911   8.921  93.880 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  54.574186   7.861912   6.942 3.11e-10 ***
Solar.R      -0.585400   0.091129  -6.424 3.76e-09 ***
Wind         -3.377150   0.601569  -5.614 1.57e-07 ***
Solar.R:Temp  0.008837   0.001142   7.736 6.03e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 20.05 on 107 degrees of freedom
  (42 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.647, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6371 
F-statistic: 65.36 on 3 and 107 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Clearly, Solar.R, Wind, and Solar.R:Temp are all highly significant. My model has some validity. Next I plot:
ggplot(data = augment(model), aes(x = Wind, y = Ozone, size = Solar.R)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(aes(y = .fitted), size = 1, fill = "purple") +
    labs(x = "Wind", y = "Ozone",
         title = "Ozone vs. Wind")

This turned up in the console:

geom_smooth() using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'

Two questions:

Is it true that geom_smooth() used method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x' for the fitted line, instead of my model? Why?
If the above is true, how can I plot my model with the original data?


For a model that is more complicated than a univariate regression, you need something like sjPlot::plot_model() or ggpredict() or ...

Yes -- looking into both. So it sounds like the answer to my 1st question is true? Thanks Ben.

Yes, it's true. geom_smooth() only knows about data from data frames, not about model predictions. If you used geom_smooth() with method = "lm" you could get a linear model, but only a univariate one (or a series of univariate linear models, one for each category distinguished by a grouping aesthetic (colour/fill/group/faceting etc.)

I was almost misled to believe the fitted line was real, until I investigated the console output. Well, I hope they can address this problem in a future upgrade of geom_smooth().

I can appreciate that you want that, but it's not how geom_smooth() is defined (and IMO it doesn't really make sense to define it that way).  There is an ever growing number of packages (marginaleffects, sjPlot, ggpredict, etc.) that are designed for the task you're trying to do.
